# Anyone have issues using cx tires on the road when its wet?

Tags: tire, commuter, cyclocross

I have a cross bike and i love the feel the fit and the response to steering that comes with cx bikes but im having a repeat issue. Using it as my daily rider when roads are wet it never fails that during a ride i find myself sliding on my hips because my tires just slip out from under me. Is this related to having knobby tires or maybe a pressure issue. Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: Knobbly tyres will always have less grip than smooth ones on smooth road. I assume the issue is just on cornering; perhaps you just need to take the corners slower on those tyres - or fit road tyres

Comment: Consider that maybe you're not a very good judge of road conditions.  When the pavement is wet you need to pick your way through corners carefully -- you cannot simply "trust" the tires, regardless of their tread and other features.

Comment: Also use caution when braking or turning on wet manhole covers and painted crosswalks  they can get very slippery.

Comment: Though your question was specifically about tires, this site provides an in-depth overview of the physics behind cornering...
http://www.coachcarl.com/training_articles/cornering.htm

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. Have sense went to a continental 4 season tire and have not had any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Yes knobs have less surface contact and do not have good road traction.

Consider road touring tires.

Comment: Touring tires often favour longevity over  traction (i.e., low traction rubber compound).  An "all seasons" road tire will have a softer rubber compound meant to provide traction in the wet.

Comment: @Rider_X Road tires don't come bigger than 30 and there are soft touring tires.